# ListView is not updating in WPF when binding to static property

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, static

I have a Class (`SensorContainer`), that contains a static List (`SensorList`).

The class looks like this:

```
public static class SensorContainer
    {

        public static List<Sensor> SensorList
        {
            get { return _sensorList; }
        }

        private static readonly List<Sensor> _sensorList = new List<Sensor>();

    }
```

In my Xaml i have a listview that i bind to that SensorList with the following code

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SensorContainer.SensorList}}">
```

The binding works actually! 
**But**...only when i do either **change the window size** or **switch to another tab of the Gui and back**!!!

**EDIT**: To use an ObservableCollection would be possible as stated by pkeuter but not a possible solution at the moment due to specifications in other parts of the program.

It has nothing to do with time or the comunication with the sensors...it just doesnt show the changes of the `SensorList`, as long as i dont play around with my Window :) ...

Anyone an idea about what the problem might be?

Comment: Another option would be to use `CollectionViewSource` and a `CompositeCollection` that will try to wrap your collection in a way that will allow the changed items to be picked up by the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection`. This will notify the UI of a change to your collection. This way, you don't have to resize your window all the time ;-)

Here is more information about the ObservableCollection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The thing is that this solution is out of discussion due to specifications of the program...i will add this information to the problem.

Comment: Well if you do not want to use an ObservableCollection you can always make a custom class and implement IObservable. This will work as well. But if you want to use binding, then you have to use a collection that implements IObservable (like ObservableCollection).

Comment: But how does it come that it actually binds(!!!) but just with weird behavior...?

Comment: Because when you initialize, the UI will get notified of an update. Then, when you update your collection, the UI will need a way to know that this collection has been changed. Hence the ICollectionChanged (I said IObservable but I meant ICollectionChanged) interface. I suggest you read the page I've posted in my answer. This will give you more information.

Comment: Thank you very much! But just out of curiosity: Would there be a way around? Something like get the window object within the code and refresh it  ?

Comment: I don't think there is. And when there is, it would definitely be a very bad practice not using an ObservableCollection. If this is absolutely impossible for you to use, it might be an idea to just update the ListView from the code. This too is a bad practice, but it works.